# Why it says always "Cannot convert value of type '' to expected argument type ''" in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have simple app below, in SwiftUI, it throw an error like "Cannot convert value of type"  I was use `AppView(count: 5, total: 10)`, still same, but I did not understand very well, which point I miss, any idea will be appreciated.

**Code:**

```
 import SwiftUI
 struct AppView: View {
 var count: Int
 var total: Int
  var fontOne: Font
  var colorOne: Color
  var showBottomText: Bool

  public init(count: Int,
              total: Int,
              progress: CGFloat,
              fontOne: Font = Font.system(size: 75, weight: .bold, design: .rounded),
              colorOne: Color = Color.primary,
              fill: LinearGradient = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.green, Color.blue]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom),
              lineWidth: CGFloat = 25.0,
              lineCap: CGLineCap = CGLineCap.round,
              showText: Bool = true,
              showBottomText: Bool = true) {

      self.count = count
      self.total = total
      self.fontOne = fontOne
      self.colorOne = colorOne
      self.showBottomText = showBottomText
  }
var body: some View {
    ZStack{
            
                if showText {
                    //Text at the centre
                    VStack {
                     
                        Text("\(count)")
                            .font(fontOne)
                            .foregroundColor(colorOne)
                        if showBottomText{
                        
                            Text("/ \(total)")
                                .font(fontOne)
                                .foregroundColor(colorOne)
                        }}}}} }

 struct AppView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
    AppView(count: Int, total: Int, progress: CGFloat)
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't actually passing in any values to your `AppView` init in your `AppView_Previews`, you just specified the input argument types. You need to pass in concrete values.

```
struct AppView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AppView(count: 5, total: 10, progress: 0.5)
    }
}
```